# Corda Bootstrapper failing after node-info generation

Tags: java, corda

I am currently working on R3 Corda 4.4 and generating my network using the network Bootstrapper tool. I have a 3 node setup which is running on 3 different VMs with a load balancer attached to each of them. I am also using postgresql as my db for the nodes. All the steps till node-info creation run successfully, during node-info creation the 2nd party's node-info is generated after the last party node-info causing an error.

```
picocli.CommandLine$ExecutionException: Error while calling command (net.corda.bootstrapper.NetworkBootstrapperRunner@4e28bdd1): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process hasn't exited
```

The error occurs as soon as the node-info for the 3rd party is generated and the 2nd party one is in progress. When I open the logs for each of the parties there is no Error and all node-info are getting generated and I can see them in their respective folders.

**Detailed Error:**

```
picocli.CommandLine$ExecutionException: Error while calling command (net.corda.bootstrapper.NetworkBootstrapperRunner@4e28bdd1): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process hasn't exited
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:1180)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$800(CommandLine.java:141)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:1367)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:1335)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.handleParseResult(CommandLine.java:1243)
        at picocli.CommandLine.parseWithHandlers(CommandLine.java:1526)
        at net.corda.cliutils.CordaCliWrapperKt.start(CordaCliWrapper.kt:73)
        at net.corda.bootstrapper.MainKt.main(Main.kt:19)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process hasn't exited
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.exitValue(UNIXProcess.java:421)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion$generateNodeInfo$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:116)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion$generateNodeInfo$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:69)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.printNodeInfoGenLogToConsole(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:128)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.generateNodeInfo(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:116)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.access$generateNodeInfo(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:69)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion$generateNodeInfos$1$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:95)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion$generateNodeInfos$1$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:69)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:141)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:153)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:22)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message unfortunately doesn't give us a lot to work with but it would seem that there's a problem with a particular node config option.

Is this issue happening when running the deploy nodes task? (meaning compiling your cordapps) Or is this issue happening when you use the runnodes script?

can you share more info on what the node configs look like? that's probably going to be the most likely culprit as it's not clear what you've changed since the last working version.

Here's my recommendation:

See if you're able to isolate the issue and run the network without the problematic node and then share the config of the one that was giving the issue.

Here's a page on the configuration options for nodes : https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/corda-configuration-fields.html

If you're able to find a specific node config option that's causing the breaking definitely update here or on slack so we can get that bug reported if it turns out to be that.

Comment: I am not running tasks from any corda project, but instead I am using the corda NetworkBootstrapper. The node confs are made as per fields. The issue is related to the Bootstrapper thread handling I guess. I have isolated the error cause to the order in which the node-info task is completed in the bootstrapper.